# Where is the civic center in Sundari (Mandalore)?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In S3E2 of *The Mandalorian* we see Din and Bo-Katan go the Mines of Mandalore to reach the living waters. We are told that the mines are below the civic center in Sundari. We see the wreckage of the domed city from above. However when they go to enter, there is no dome in sight.

[image]

We get a nice view of this buried city. Light streams in from above, which could be an upper layer to the city, but there seems to be no real connection to any upper levels.

[image]

So my question, **where in the city is this?** It doesnt seem to be connected to the dome at all, unless it is an underground extension to the city, several miles away from the main dome.

Comment: The planet was bombed the hell out of during the Purge, it's more than likely that this part of the city was buried by rubble or crumbling architecture during the bombings...

Comment: Where's the civic centre? Just above the mines 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a definitive answer to this since it's not like they've ever released any kind of map of the city; but going by the top image, you can see voids which show that the city extends well below ground level.

Indeed if one has a look through the various establishing shots of the interior seen during the course of 'Clone Wars', it's notable that some are clearly on the "surface", and others (like the prison complex & Academy) are in an deeper layer.

The main giveaways are the more limited sunlight from above, the lack of any ground street level (only suspended walkways), and stalactite-like buildings can be seen hanging down from above in some shots. Not exactly like the city layers on Coruscant since Sundari has a lot more open space between the upper and lower layer, but it's a similar arrangement nonetheless. I think Rook Kast even has a line in 'Old Friends Not Forgotten' mentioning the "lower city" when reporting that Ahsoka was spotted heading down to the "under city", the latter of which referring to the networks of service tunnels. Said tunnels were also seen in 'The Mandalorian', and sure enough, they were right under where that second image depicts.

So with all that in mind it seems reasonably to presume that the civics centre was in the lower city.